# looping inside cloud build for multiple deployments

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-deploy

I'm trying to create multiple deployments using Cloud Build and Cloud Deploy in GKE cluster. Below is my `cloudbuild.yaml`

```
steps:
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: 
  - '-c'
  - |
    while IFS= read -r deplname; do
      sed -i "s/service/$$deplname/g" ./test/deployment.yaml
      release_name=$$(echo "build-$$RANDOM")
      gcloud deploy releases create $$release_name --project=PROJECT_ID --region=us-central1 --delivery-pipeline=test-cloud-deploy --source=. --images=test-cloud-deploy=us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/PROJECT_ID/cicd-test/test-image:v1
    done < ./consumer_names.txt
options:
 logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
```

my `consumer_names.txt` looks like,

```
deployment-name1
deployment-name2
```

`deployment.yaml` looks like,

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: service
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

But it's creating only one deployment that is `deployment-name1` not second. Is there any way to create multiple deployments using cloud build and cloud deploy ?

Comment: You are missing a ; at the end of the gcloud deploy line

Comment: @boredabdel adding `;` at the end of line `gcloud deploy ...` doesn't make any difference. Only one deployment got created. Any suggestion ?

Comment: The semi-colon should make no difference because you're using YAML pipe (`|`) so everything that follows is treated as multi-line. None of the semi-colons is needed. It's curious that you create `deplname` but don't use it so you make it more difficult to debug that it's being read correctly. It's also curious that you `release_name=$$(echo "build-$$RANDOM")`, `release_name="build-$$RANDOM"` should suffice. If you `printf "%s: %s" ${deplname} ${release_name}` you'll ensure that you're iterating and generating unique `release_name`s

Comment: And... you should reference `release_name` "locally" (i.e. `${release_name}` **not** `$$release_name`) within the script because it's **not** being substituted by Cloud Build but by the shell.

Comment: Sorry typo `release_name="build-${RANDOM}"` too. Not being substituted by Cloud Shell but the local shell.

Comment: @DazWilkin I have used `deplname` in cloudbuild.yaml it was missed here. I have updated question again.

Comment: @DazWilkin my ultimate goal is to deploy multiple deployment in GKE cluster using single template. Is there any better way to do that ?

Comment: Ah, I see. Did you apply the other changes I proposed? That should get you to a working config. I think your script isn't working correctly and you're not seeing that it doesn't work because you don't log (e.g. `echo`) state. The changes should get you to a working script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248270/discussion-between-rahul-and-dazwilkin).

Comment: Please update the scripts with the recommendations and try that. Your `sed` for the Deployment is incorrect too. You don't want to use `$$VARIABLE` for variables that are defined **within** the script. `$$VARIABLE` is used to tell Cloud Build to substitute variables that you provide when you invoke Cloud Build.